# Outlook Add-ins, how to I restrict access to it?

Tags: office365, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook web add-in which can be installed into Outlook via a manifest file.
But how do I prevent everyone/anyone who has the URL to my manifest file in installing my add-in as well?

Is there some section in the manifest I can use or can I configure the IIS hosting the add-in to somehow block this?

Answer (score 0):

In the O365 Administrator Console that you can simply:

1. Click SETTINGS
2. SERVICES & ADD-INS
3. USER OWNED APPS AND SERVICES
4. uncheck LET USERS ACCESS THE OFFICE STORE
5. uncheck LET USERS INSTALL TRIAL APPS AND SERVICES
6. SAVE CHANGES

Read more about that in the [SOLVED: How To Block Users From Installing Add-Ins In Outlook & OWA on Office 365 Hosted Exchange](https://www.urtech.ca/2019/08/solved-how-to-block-users-from-installing-add-ins-in-outlook-owa-on-office-365-hosted-exchange/) article.

Comment: I am not trying to deny everyone access to the add-in, I am trying to deny everyone access to the add-in who are not part of a certain domain - like the customer's domain aka "@domain.com". All accounts of the customer should be allowed to install it. Everyone else, not.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is nothing in the manifest that blocks installation of the add-in. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.